# Date description

Tags: iphone, calendar

How can I retrieve the dates of my events from my iPhone?
I've just got an sqlitedb file left. Which was luckily stored on my pc. But how do I decipher which date and time it is?

Below is the table of my calendar...

http://img696.imageshack.us/i/calendersqlite.jpg/

Answer (score 0):

SQLite knows different ways to encode a date.
I would use a reader like this http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/ which could help.
Have a looke here http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html (1.2) maybe you can find whihc format is used in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)
I think it's a unix timestamp (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)
But how does SQlite generate them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? And I guess the developer created the entry in his code - by using one of the date functions.